# How to count characters on strings in vb6

Tags: vb6

Good day! I have a problem in visual basic 6.0
The goal is to count how many words and characters.

For example :

Electric Fan

Words : 2
Characters : 11

I already done the code for the word.

But I have no idea how to count characters.
Thanks!

Anyway this is my code for counting words :

```
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim StartPos As Integer


If Trim(Text1) = "" Then
    NumOfWords = 0
    Exit Sub
End If

Text1 = Trim(Text1) ' Remove All Spaces

NumOfWords = 1
For Counter = 1 To Len(Text1)
        If Mid(Text1, Counter, 1) = " " Then
                NumOfWords = NumOfWords + 1
        End If
Next Counter

Text2.Text = NumOfWords
Text3.Text = Index
```

Comment: How about `Len(word)`?

Comment: can you elaborate? I'm totally new here. =(
i don't know every keywords.

Comment: Why not try it? Or look it up online? If you provide the code you have so far, it would be easier to determine the problem.

Comment: Well this is my code for counting words and so far, I don't have any for characters.

Dim Counter As Integer
Dim StartPos As Integer


If Trim(Text1) = "" Then
    NumOfWords = 0
    Exit Sub
End If
 
Text1 = Trim(Text1) ' Remove All Spaces
 
NumOfWords = 1
For Counter = 1 To Len(Text1)
        If Mid(Text1, Counter, 1) = " " Then
                NumOfWords = NumOfWords + 1
        End If
Next Counter
 
Text2.Text = NumOfWords
Text3.Text = Index

Comment: Ah, I see. How about this: what if `Mid(Text1, Counter, 1) <> " "`?

Comment: Please don't delete your questions to post them again. Deleted questions still count towards question ban. Improve them instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function that does that. It was not as obvious to write it as I expected. Here I assume that you only want to count letters. But that may not be the case. See http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions for ASCII Character Codes and modify the code according to what you mean by the word "character".

```
Private Function countLetters(str As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim symbol As String

    countLetters = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        symbol = Mid(str, i, 1)
        If isLetter(symbol) Then
            countLetters = countLetters + 1
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Function isLetter(symbol As String) As Boolean
    isLetter = (Asc(symbol) >= 65 And Asc(symbol) <= 90) Or (Asc(symbol) >= 97 And Asc(symbol) <= 122) Or Asc(symbol) >= 161
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you only use a space as separation between the words, so you could use the code below:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 textbox: name=Text1
'  2 command buttons: name=Command1    name=Command2
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngWord As Long
  Dim lngWords As Long, lngChars As Long
  Dim strWord() As String
  'split your text over each space
  strWord = Split(Text1.Text, " ")
  'count the words
  lngWords = UBound(strWord)
  'loop over all words and count the chars
  lngChars = 0
  For lngWord = 0 To lngWords
    lngChars = lngChars + Len(strWord(lngWord))
  Next lngWord
  'show the results
  ShowResults lngWords + 1, lngChars
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Dim lngWords As Long, lngChars As Long
  Dim strText As String
  strText = Text1.Text
  'count spaces
  lngWords = Len(strText) - Len(Replace(strText, " ", ""))
  'count all except spaces
  lngChars = Len(strText) - lngWords
  'show the results
  ShowResults lngWords + 1, lngChars
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Text1.Text = "Electric Fan"
End Sub

Private Sub ShowResults(lngWords As Long, lngChars As Long)
  MsgBox "Words: " & CStr(lngWords) & vbCrLf & "Chars: " & CStr(lngChars), vbInformation, "Count"
End Sub
```

Command1 and Command2 should give the same result.

Command1 is probably more easy to understand, and gives you an array containing all words in the end.
Command2 is less code :)

Some remarks:

- words can also be separated by ,.:;() and many more
- words can also be separated when your text continues on a new line
- there could be 2 separation characters without a word in between, like accidently 2 spaces
- words can continue on the next line. this should count as 1 word, but has a newline in between and probably a -

If you want to take other characters into account, then you might have to write your own split() or own replace() functions

Comment: (+1) You might want to consider other white spaces in the text as well as double spaces (e.g. after full stops etc).  Try adding something like: `Do While Instr(strText, "  ")>0` [crlf] `strText = Replace(strText, "  ", " ")` [crlf] `Loop`.  I know this is only standard (`Chr(32)`) spaces, but this could be turned into a function to check for tabs (`Chr(9)`), [non-breaking spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) and other [white space characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Comment: thanks for the links! ... also pay attention to words which might be wrapped to the next line, they should count as 1 word, while there is a newline and probably a - in between

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to get very close to MS Word's counters like this

```
lNumOfWords = CountWords(TextToCount)

Private Function CountWords(Text As String, Optional Pattern As String = "\S+") As Long
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = Pattern
        CountWords = .Execute(Text).Count
    End With
End Function
```

To count characters (no spaces) use

```
lNumOfChars = CountWords(TextToCount, "\S")
```

For large string probably a more performant approach for words counting would be something like this

```
lNumOfWords = CountWords(TextToCount, "\b") \ 2
```

because when splitting on boundaries (the `\b` pattern) the returned matches collection will contain empty strings only.

More on VBScript regexps supported patterns [here](http://www.kingsley-hughes.com/tech/script/vbscript/regular_expressions_vbscript.php).